# Django Rest Framework not saving reference to Many to Many

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model (Notifications) that has a Many-to-Many relationship (NotifictionGroups).  Serializing data coming out of the models works just fine with DRF but when I want to save to Notification referencing the Many-to-Many relationships I get nothing.

Models:

```
class Notifications(models.Model):
    notification = models.CharField(max_length='125')
    groups = models.ManyToManyField('NotificationGroups')

class NotificationGroups(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length='100')
```

Serializers:

```
class NotificationGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = NotificationGroups
        fields = ('id', 'name',)

class NotificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = NotificationGroupSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Notifications
        fields = ('id', 'notification', 'groups',)
```

JSON body of the request:

```
{
   "notification":"This is a test from the API",
   "groups":[
      {
         "id":1
      },
      {
         "id":3
      }
   ]
}
```

ViewSet:

```
def create(self, request):
    serializer = NotificationSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        print serializer.validated_data

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

When I save there is nothing saved for the Notification Groups.  I am printing the validated data in the ViewSet at the moment just to test but I do not get any of the group data.

I realize I am missing something obvious here but I have not been able to find my issue. All the examples I can find talk about writing the Many-To-Many data as new data, not referencing it as I need here.

**Edit with fix:**

Serializers:

```
class NotificationGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = NotificationGroups
        fields = ('id', 'name',)

class NotificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Notifications
        fields = ('id', 'notification', 'groups',)
```

JSON body of the request:

```
{
   "notification":"This is a test from the API",
   "groups":[1, 3]
}
```

Comment: Could you paste an output from that print ?

Comment: Request:  {u'notification': u'This is a test from the API', u'notification_groups': [{u'id': 1}, {u'id': 3}]}
Print of the validated_data:  OrderedDict([(u'notification', u'This is a test from the API')])

Comment: I ended up solving this on my own.  Turns out I was trying to do too much and needed to scale back a bit.  Once I removed the NotificationGroupSerializer reference from the NotificationSerializer this started to work as expected.

Comment: Working on this for several hours now... Apperently when you do a POST with POSTman as "form-data", the array is getting transformed in a string. So when you send raw data it works... It's not an issue with DRF.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `create` and `update` functions in your serializer. DRF doesn't support writable nested serializers by default.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations

Comment: If I print validated_data I don't even see the `groups`.  The data isn't even making it to the ViewSet for me to run through a custom create/update function.  The issue seems to be somewhere in the serializer?